# How to tell wget where to fetch files passed via '--input-file'

Tags: wget, download

I have a list of filenames (not urls) in a file, and I want to download them using `--input-file` option. How do I specify the url where those files will be fetched from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`--base` option](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Logging-and-Input-File-Options.html):

```
wget -i file-of-filenames --base http://example.com/fetch/from/here/
```